# How do I scroll the comments in a Youtube Video? I have tired

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I'm trying to build a Youtube Scraper. I've scrapped all the data I wanted from the video but I am not able to scroll all the way to the end of the comments.

I have tried the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8jN69GEBSw"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 1000)')
time.sleep(0.5)
```

I've tried "Keys" as well but it is not working either

I think the problem is this code returning 0.

```
driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
```

Could you someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use selenium .scroll_by_amount function. You need to do something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8jN69GEBSw"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
ActionChains(driver).scroll_by_amount(0,5000).perform()
```

You need to find right amount for second parameter. There are some other options like .scroll_from_origin or .scroll_to_element. If that will not be what you want. Try one of these. I recommend to add options and add argument to options, which is "--start-maximized"